# $\lim_{n\to\infty }n\sin (\frac{1}{n^{2}+1})$

Tags: real-analysis

$$\lim_{n\to\infty }\,n\,\sin\frac{1}{n^{2}+1}$$
How to solve this limit? It seems to be 0. But I don't know how to justify it.
Thanks for your help

Comment: The last $n$ is outside $\sin$ or inside?

Comment: @Speedding Then it would be wise, I think, to write that $\;n\;$ **before** the sine, namely $$n\sin\frac1{n^2+1}$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty }\sin (\frac{1}{n^{2}+1})n&=\lim_{n\to\infty }\frac{\sin (\frac{1}{n^{2}+1})}{\frac1{n^2+1}}\times \frac1{n^2+1}n\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty }\frac{\sin (\frac{1}{n^{2}+1})}{\frac1{n^2+1}} \times \lim_{n\to\infty } \frac n{n^2+1}\\
&=1 \times 0
\end{align}

Where you may recall that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$.

Comment: Wow it seems to be pretty easy and elegant solution. Thank you very much

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Use
$$
|\sin x|\le\min(|x|,1).
$$
to find $$\frac{n}{1+n^2}$$ as upper bound of the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the Taylor series of $\sin(x)$:

$$\sin(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+1} = x - \frac{x^{3}}{3!} + \frac{x^{5}}{3!}+\mathcal{O}(x^{6})$$

So:

$$\sin\left(\frac{1}{n^{2}+1}\right) = \frac{1}{n^{2}+1}-\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{(n^{2}+1)^{3}}\right)$$

So Taylor expanding our limit:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\sin\left(\frac{1}{n^{2}+1}\right) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n}{n^{2}+1} - \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{n}{(n^{2}+1)^{3}}\right)\right) = 0$$

As you have found numerically.

Answer (score 1):

let $$k=\frac{1}{n}$$

So

$$\lim_{k \to 0}\frac{\sin(\frac{k^2}{1+k^2})}{k}$$
$$\lim_{k \to 0}\frac{k}{1+k^2}\frac{\sin(\frac{k^2}{1+k^2})}{\frac{k^2}{1+k^2}}=0$$